# Working with online users based on their IP address address - mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Right now I have a box (in footer) where I'm showing online users based on three types of url location, the user type and his Ip address.

I'm using individual querys to delete, insert and show online users, but I really need more performance because I'm not sure whether this is the fastest way to do this. And maybe if somebody see any bad practice in my code.

Here we go:

Types of url location:

1. Empty url ( www.example.com )
2. Url like www.example.com/forum/123/
3. Url like www.example.com/topic/123/

Types of user:

1. Visitors
2. Registered users

This is the way how I get the user IP address:

```
$ip_lookup = array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'REMOTE_ADDR');
foreach($ip_lookup as $server_param)
{
    if(isset($_SERVER[$server_param]) && filter_var($_SERVER[$server_param], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        if(filter_var($_SERVER[$server_param], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6))
        {
            define('dpd_ip_type','v6');
        }
        else
        {
            define('dpd_ip_type','v4');
        }
        define('dpd_ip',inet_pton($_SERVER[$server_param]));
        break;
    }
}
if(!defined('dpd_ip') || dpd_ip === false) { error('error_ip'); exit(); }
```

Here I have an array (one of them are based on type of url or on type of user):

```
$online['dpd_ip'] = dpd_ip; /* The ip (ipv4 or ipv6) - this was converted as binary width inet_pton */
$online['dpd_ip_type'] = dpd_ip_type; /* The ip type (ipv4 or ipv6) */
$online['dpd_time'] = dpd_time; /* The current time in Unix Timestamp format */
$online['url'] = ''; /* The url location - Empty by default */
$online['user_id'] = ''; /* The user id - Empty by default */
$online['user_name'] = ''; /* The user name - Empty by default */
$online['get_online_users_where'] = ''; /* The where clause used for for output records - empty by default */
$online['online_clear_where'] = ''; /* The where clause used for deleting records - empty by default */

if(is_user())
{
    $online['user_id'] = user_id; /* Set user_id because we talk about an registered user */
    $online['user_name'] = user_name; /* Set user_name because we talk about an registered user */
    $online['online_clear_where'] = " OR online_user_id = ".user_id; /* Set where clause for deleting this user before insert him again */
}

if(defined('url_1') && defined('url_2') && (url_1 == 'topic' || url_1 == 'forum'))
{
    $online['url'] = url_1.'/'.url_2; /* The url is a section like forum/123/ or topic/123 */
    $online['get_online_users_where'] = " WHERE online_url = '".url_1.'/'.url_2."'"; /* Output the user that are accessed this url location */
}
```

Here I start working with the databse:

```
pdo('begin');

/* Delete records from database if:
    - The records are bigger than 15 minutes ( dpd_footer_online_time is set to 900 seconds )
    - This is the actual user 
*/
$online_clear = pdo("DELETE FROM online WHERE online_timestamp < ".(dpd_time - dpd_footer_online_time)." OR online_ip_".$online['dpd_ip_type']." = '".$online['dpd_ip']."'" . $online['online_clear_where']);

/* Insert the user into database */
$online = pdo("
    INSERT INTO
        online
        (
            online_user_id,
            online_user_name,
            online_ip_".$online['dpd_ip_type'].",
            online_timestamp,
            online_url
        )
    VALUES
    (
        '".$online['user_id']."',
        '".$online['user_name']."',
        '".$online['dpd_ip']."',
        '".$online['dpd_time']."',
        '".$online['url']."'
    )
    "
);

/* Output the users from the last 15 minutes */
$get_online_users = pdo("SELECT online_user_id, online_user_name, online_timestamp FROM online".$online['get_online_users_where']);
pdo('commit');
```

And of course, this is the table ( online_ip_v4 and online_ip_v6 are uniques ):

[image]

Any suggestion is welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE online;` so we can see what indexes (if any) you have, etc.

Use assignment statements, not `define(...)`.

Use binding, not concatenation -- you are vulnerable to "SQL Injection".

Split the DELETE into two (or three) DELETEs -- one for each side of the OR.  (OR does not optimize well.)

You probably need

```
INDEX(online_timestamp)
UNIQUE(online_ip_v4)
UNIQUE(online_ip_v6)
INDEX(user_id)
```

What do you do for sites that don't have both IPv4 and IPv6?

Please provide the query/queries for "show online users".